# Mocking tool for python-3.3

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking, python-3.3

I have a few classes that rely on `time.perf_counter()` to timestamp events and do things after a certain amount of time passes, like this:

```
class Alarm:
    def setAlarm(self):
        self.alarmed = False
        self._saved = time.perf_counter()

    def runStep(self):
        now = time.perf_counter()
        if now - self._saved > 1000.0 and self._saved != -1:
            self.alarmed = True
            self._saved = -1
```

I would like to test the class `Alarm` using a fake clock, it does not necessary to be a call to `time.perf_counter()` (though it would be more elegant if it does, I guess). I want that the fake clock does not increment by itself, but rather upon my command, like this:

```
    alarm = Alarm()
    alarm.setAlarm()
    clock.increment(999.0)
    alarm.runStep()
    self.assertFalse(alarm.alarmed)
    clock.increment(1.1)    # tick another second
    alarm.runStep()
    self.assertTrue(alarm.alarmed)
```

Could you please advise on how to mock `time.perf_counter()` or mock my class for it, and what kind of tool should be used for this kind of job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unittest.mock`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).

For example:

```
import time
import unittest
import unittest.mock

class Alarm:
    def setAlarm(self):
        self.alarmed = False
        self._saved = time.perf_counter()
    def runStep(self):
        now = time.perf_counter()
        if now - self._saved > 1000.0 and self._saved != -1:
            self.alarmed = True
            self._saved = -1

class MockPerfCounter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = 0
    def increment(self, n):
        self.t += n
    def perf_counter(self):
        return self.t

class TestAlarm(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        clock = MockPerfCounter()
        with unittest.mock.patch('time.perf_counter', clock.perf_counter):
            alarm = Alarm()
            alarm.setAlarm()
            clock.increment(999.0)
            alarm.runStep()
            self.assertFalse(alarm.alarmed)
            clock.increment(1.1)    # tick another second
            alarm.runStep()
            self.assertTrue(alarm.alarmed)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

---

Alterantively, instead of manual `MockPerfCounter`, you can also use [`unittest.mock.Mock`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class):

```
class TestAlarm(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_foo(self):
        clock = unittest.mock.Mock()
        clock.t = 0
        with unittest.mock.patch('time.perf_counter', lambda: clock.t):
            alarm = Alarm()
            alarm.setAlarm()
            clock.t += 999.0
            alarm.runStep()
            self.assertFalse(alarm.alarmed)
            clock.t += 1.1
            alarm.runStep()
            self.assertTrue(alarm.alarmed)
```

Comment: This was most helpful, however, I have noticed that if import `perf_counter` as in `from time import perf_counter` than the above patch does no longer work, is there a way to patch a function imported like this?

Comment: @dkrikun, Replace `unittest.mock.patch('time.perf_counter', ...)` with `unittest.mock.patch('__main__.perf_counter', ..)`.